# JavaScript .each function saving last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I have a function with a loop that save data in an object,
the foreach loop is saving the last value

```
var n = new Array();
    var weight  =   new Array();
    var obj =   {};
    var as  =   [];
    // var temp;
   
    $("input:checked").each(function(){
        temp    = this.value;
        // n.push(this.value);
        obj['ids']  =   temp;
        obj['weight']=  $("#weight"+temp).val();
        as.push(obj);
        delete temp;
    }); 
     console.log(as);
```

[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0T3U.png)

the result of console.log is

> (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> 0: {ids: "298", weight: "1.00"}
>
> 1: {ids: "298", weight: "1.00"}
>
> 2: {ids: "298", weight: "1.00"}
>
> 3: {ids: "298", weight: "1.00"}
>
> 4: {ids: "298", weight: "1.00"}

this should be

> (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> 0: {ids: "on", weight: "undefined"}
>
> 1: {ids: "4", weight: "1"}
>
> 2: {ids: "5", weight: "2"}
>
> 3: {ids: "6", weight: "3"}
>
> 4: {ids: "298", weight: "4"}

Comment: Can you share the HTML that you are working with for this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the *same reference* to the object in every `push()` call. Create a new object in every iteration by moving `var obj = {};` inside the loop. Also, if you define `temp` within the loop you don't need to use `delete temp` - not that it's of any use in this instance anyway.

```js
var n = [], weight = [], as = [];

$("input:checked").each(function() {
  var temp = this.value;
  var obj = {};
  obj['ids'] = temp;
  obj['weight'] = $("#weight" + temp).val();
  as.push(obj);
});

console.log(as);
```

That being said, you can improve the logic by using `map()` instead:

```js
let as = $("input:checked").map(function() {
  let temp = this.value;
  return {
    ids: temp,
    weight: $("#weight" + temp).val()
  }
}).get();

console.log(as);
```

Comment: you put a much better answer so I am deleting mine

Comment: thanks, that works, I'll mark this as correct answer

Comment: No problem, glad to help